# 'Run As' box popping up when program runs on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, unsigned

I have a program that was written in house years ago by someone who has now left. The program should run (minimized in the task bar) when I login which it does but before it can run I see the 'Run As' window below. The program isn't signed which may be the problem. I'm logged on as an administrator. Can anyone tell me why I see the 'Run As' box? It runs fine on Windows 7 but I need to add it to a Windows XP PC.

The program is set to run from the registry via HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.

Many thanks
James

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other need for the RunAs feature then you could first try stopping the service. open the run command and type services.msc then scroll down to "Secondary Logon" and disable this service.